# Fatal error: Call to a member function setOrder() on a non-object in Magenotification.php

Tags: magento, admin

My website developed in magento is running well but when I try to open admin

```
www.mysite.com/admin
```

its trowing the following fatal error :

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function setOrder() on a non-object in
 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification
 /Mode/Magenotification.php on line 200
```

Please help me to solve the problem.?